# How to access getIntent() from extends AppCompatActivity to extends Application

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity

So, my Activity A is :

```
public class imei extends AppCompatActivity {
//variables    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imei);    
        ...    
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(Long.parseLong(IMEI) == IMEI2){
                    IMEI .equals(IMEI2);
                    textView.setText("IMEI NUMBER : " + IMEI);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putBoolean("key", true);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(imei.this, menu_utama.class);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    imei.this.startActivity(intent);
                }else{}
```

now i want to pass value the Boolean value from bundle to Activity B :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private BeaconManager beaconManager;    
    //variables

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        final boolean success = bundle.getBoolean("key");    
        ..code
            if(success){
                do something
            }else{do something
```

but the `getIntent()` is red, but when i change to `extends AppCompatActivity`, `getIntent()` correct. somehow it has to do with `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `extends Application` what should i do to fix this

Comment: `now i want to pass value the Boolean value from bundle to Activity B :` what do you mean? Do you want to pass to activity or application?

Comment: i want to pass the value from activity A, but getIntent() is red in Activity B, somehow because extends Application

Comment: please make this clear **application is not an ACTIVITY** BOTH ARE COMPLETELY CLASS

Comment: if you want to pass value to application.. you can pass it via constructor..

Comment: yes passing value to application, any link guide example please

Comment: i heard from someone, using Shared Preference.

Comment: ya you can use watever way you want.. you can pass it via constructor too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my problem is how to passing value between activity class to aplication class, first try i'm using Bundle which is using getIntent(), but it did not work because getIntent() is in activity class, because i want to using in application class, so i'm using shared Preference and it works.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("masuk", true);
                    // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
                    editor.apply(); // commit changes
```

put it in activity class and get the shared preferences in application class:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("masuk", true);
        // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
        editor.apply(); // commit changes
```

and then just use `if(masuk){do what you want here}else{do what you want here}`
Solved.